# Having issues responding to an HTTP request with the proper array. Possible way to send results from within function with expressjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, node-sqlite3

Problem Summary: So I'm working on a program that has an SQL database on the backend and I'm using the npm SQLite3 module to talk to it. When I make my HTTP request to the server I was told in another post that I should do a `res.send` with the function inside it so after the function ran, it would return whatever came from the function. Easy enough right? But then I ran into an issue with an asynchronous function `.all` [(API Doc here)](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseallsql-param--callback). Essentially what happens is that I call my database and it returns everything inside to an object inside database.all, but database.all is an asynchronous function that is void and can't return anything. I've got a callback that sends the object inside the callback, but I don't know what to do with it from there, or if I even need a callback.

So my question is: can I send an HTTP response from somewhere inside my `.all` function or callback, or does my function have to return the array to where it was called? Code below to show you what I mean.

Chain of events [(Github repo for refrence)](https://github.com/R-Dubz/DaycareScheduler):

I've set up an angular controller to send the following HTTP request when my page loads:

```
$http.get('/LoadWaitingList')
.then(function(response) {
    // alert("HTTP request set, getting data");
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

and when the server (server.js) receives it, I do this:

```
app.get('/LoadWaitingList', function (req, res) {
  res.send(DatabaseFunction.loadWaitingList());
})
```

which runs the loadWaitingList() function in another file named test.js:

```
function  loadWaitingList() {
    var callbackFunction = function(err, response){
        var returnRow = response;
        return returnRow;
    }
    updateDB.Manager(callbackFunction);
}
```

which calls `updateDB.Manager`, AKA this guy:

```
Manager : function(callback){
    var fs = require("fs");
    var file = "./Source/Server/Data/DaycareDB.db";
    var exists = fs.existsSync(file);
    if (!exists) {
        throw new Error("File not Found");
    }
    var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
    var db = new sqlite3.Database(file);
    db.all("SELECT * FROM WaitingList", function(err, row) {
        if (err){
            callback(err);
            return;
        }
        // console.log(row[0].ChildName);                   
        callback(null, row);
        return;
    });
},
```

So finally we can see, after `db.all` runs, the values I'm after after in `row`. `row` is passed into `db.all` as a parameter and returned as an array, I've tried declaring it outside the `db.all` and passing it in and then printing out the results, but due to `db.all` being asynchronous it always comes up empty because the function hasn't run yet.

When I run my callback and check the object (using vscode debugger) after the callback has been called, `returnRow` has the proper data in it from my database.

How do I send the data that gets put into `row` and eventually `returnRow` back as a response? Is it possible to do the initial function call when we get the HTTP request a different way and then do a `res.send` from the callback or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at your callbacks.

```
app.get('/LoadWaitingList', function (req, res) {
  DatabaseFunction.loadWaitingList(function(err,data){
    if(err) {
      // handle the error here
    }
    // send the data
    res.send(data);
  }
});
```

Now `loadWaitingList()` needs to take a standard error-first callback as a parameter. This callback is passed through to `updateDB.Manager()` where it will be executed.

```
function loadWaitingList(callback) {
  updateDB.Manager(callback);
}
```

Comment: WOAH!!! Didn't realize you could do that. I now feel very stupid for missing that but THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! :) thus makes so much more sense

Comment: +1 for answering quicker than me! @Ryan, if you're just getting started with javascript / node, I highly recommend these books:  https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS. They're very good and free to read online. I also highly recommend looking into Promises and Generators, which are covered in these books. Javascript is moving away from using callbacks for handling asynchronous code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a callback into your `loadWaitingList` function and then trigger `res.send` from inside that callback. Something like:

```
app.get('/LoadWaitingList', function (req, res) {
  DatabaseFunction.loadWaitingList(function(err, response) {
    res.send(response);
  });
});

function loadWaitingList(callback) {
  updateDB.Manager(callback);
}
```

This way, the `res.send` isn't triggered until your `loadWaitingList` function completes. Obviously, this code is very basic. I'm not checking for errors and the `loadWaitingList` is simply passing the supplied `callback` on to the `Manager` method. You could probably refactor this and remove `loadWaitingList` altogether.

```
app.get('/LoadWaitingList', function (req, res) {
  updateDB.Manager(function(err, response) {
    res.send(response);
  });
});
```

Just remember that any code you want to run asynchronously has to be inside a callback. The `res.send` in your original code wasn't inside a callback, so it was running immediately. Therefore, it was completing before `loadWaitingList` could return a value.

Hope this helps.